# How to copy data between 2 tables with an extra field in first table which has to be updated by a default value?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have 2 tables
Table NAME (id, name, phone, city, state, rid)
Table NAMES2 (id, name, phone, city)

This SQL statment is not working:
INSERT INTO NAME (id, name, phone, city, rid) VALUES ((SELECT id, name, phone, citY from NAMES2 WHERE city="Bangalore"),'72')

I want rid field in Table NAME to have 72 for all the records inserted from table NAMES2.
Note: both the tables are not identical.

Comment: Do you insert data into it from other tables as well?  Or can you just make the default value `72` for if it's not entered, and just specify it for any other insert query?

Comment: Ignore that.  Devart's answer is what you want.

Comment: Hi James, None of the sql queries ar working, pl help asap

Comment: Devart it is working, your first query, Thank you so much !

Comment: The second one should work too;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this query -

```
INSERT INTO NAME (id, name, phone, city, rid)
  SELECT id, name, phone, citY, 72 FROM NAMES2 WHERE city = 'Bangalore'
```

If field `rid` has default value 72 (run SHOW CREATE TABLE to view it), then you can use this query -

```
INSERT INTO NAME (id, name, phone, city)
  SELECT id, name, phone, citY FROM NAMES2 WHERE city = 'Bangalore'
```

Comment: I have mentioned the error below for the sql statement given by Devart, pl check below comment for AlexS sql query. Had forgot to mention that both the tables are not identical.

Comment: Sorry Devart, Your first query works absolutely fine: INSERT INTO NAME (id, name, phone, city, rid)
  SELECT id, name, phone, citY, 72 FROM NAMES2 WHERE city = 'Bangalore'